# Can I use the Apple Time Capsule as a NAS?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

1) Can I use Time Capsule as server? Can I run operating systems on it?

2) I'm using Time Machine with my Mac with Time Capsule.

Let's say my Mac crashes, and I cannot use it anymore. Can I restore my Mac disk on another laptop from Time Capsule?

In other words, can I have a perfect copy of my Mac hard disk on another Mac?

Comment: In the future, I really recommend posting separate questions, and use a descriptive title. I could have partly answered this and [your other](http://superuser.com/questions/146621/apple-airport-extreme-3-questions) combined question (and *different* than their current existing answers), but now I just don't know how to do so in the spirit of a Q&A site. (Even more: the 2nd item in the above question is about Time Machine, not about Time Capsule.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, since it is a NAS (Network Attached Storage) server, which practically means that it only delivers network storage space. It is already running a minimal operating system which makes the whole drive a network share. I don't know abuot the time capsule but ***SOME*** NAS servers are able to be hacked to run other operating systems.

2) I do not think you can make a perfect copy of your Mac's HDD to another Mac, the closest you would get would probably be to copy your documents and stuff from the Time Capsule to the other Mac.

Comment: As for 2), see TUAW's [6 easy steps to migrate your Mac using Time Machine](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/10/29/6-easy-steps-to-migrate-your-mac-using-time-machine/)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use the TC's backup to restore it to another machine: You can either do it from a completely blank machine using a Leopard (or preferably later) install DVD or you can use Migration assistant from the within a fresh install of the same OSX version as the backup.

Note: there's currently an issue with attempting a complete restore to a new Snow Leopard (10.6.6+) installation from an older [Snow] Leopard install DVD which seems to be due to the introduction of the App Store in 10.6.6. To work around it you need to copy the Security framework from a 10.6.6 installation (e.g. [10.6.6 update](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1343)) as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13086352?messageID=13086352#13086352).